# Does Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 Edition have driver for windows?

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, samsung-mobile

On Windows 7, I use the ADT bundle downloaded from google's android developer website, then I learned from the tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html that I need to download Samsung OEM driver, but when I search their website, http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-P6000ZWVXAR, the download data is not available, how can I connect my device in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may seem somewhat longwinded, but the only way I got mine to work was by [downloading Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/). The drivers are bundled in the download.

Alternately, they have [the driver on its own](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows), but this still didn't fix the issue for me-- I had to download Kies.

Comment: Thanks! It took me long time to find out that your solution really works, more specifically it should be Kies3 for my device.